# Can we restrict/disable concurrent logins of a user in Azure

Tags: azure

We have developed angular UI with MSAL authentication, in that one user is able to login to the application simultaneously from two different locations.

Is that any possibility to disable the concurrent logins in azure?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (If you think it somehow helps security, it doesn't (and wrecks UX) - and anyway, session/key revocation is a _hard problem_ in distributed systems like OIDC which MSAL uses).

Answer (score -1):

We can restrict concurrent user login process in 2 ways

Solution 1:

Enable multi-factor authentication (MFA) to enhance login security and reduce login risk. Once MFA is enabled, it could require the user who is logging in to confirm by using a phone call or text code after entering the user password. This will have the same effect as restricting multiple sessions for a single user.

Solution 2:

Capture the JWT token in the backend database and verify the user sessions via API calls.

For example:
The user logs in using device123, then saves the token in the database and sends it to the token in the API for use on the front end. If the same user tries to login with device 321, then the user will successfully login with the old token or place a condition and refresh the user session.

Comment: None of your suggested "solutions" can scale, and using MFA has nothing to do with session invalidation.

Comment: As per my view, solution 2, which I propose, is the right one because the auth token should be validated before the sign-in process. Why I suggested MFA is that each user should register with a phone number or email address, and then notify the logins. Please suggest if there are any other alternative options.  Appreciated!